# add a form value with '<br>' tag

Tags: javascript, tags, javascript-injection

Is it possible to add a form value with `<br>` tag in the jQuery ajaxForm?

I know it smells of script injection but it's a valid value. The string will be like this:

```
"Item1<br>Item2<br>Item3"
```

Comment: Wouldn't it work just adding `\n`?

Comment: Why does it smell of script injection?

Comment: @SergioAlen I'm being lazy cuz I need to output the text in html output. I can simply use a separator to replace '<br>' and then replace the break tags back on the server before spitting it out. I was only wondering if this was possible/straightforward instead of doing string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to insert `<br>` tags to an element, you can use jQuery's [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method to add it:

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv">

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#myDiv").append("Item1<br>Item2<br>Item3");
```

Comment: No, it's actually a form that I need to add data to.